App is not opening
I have installed 'Touchtyper' app from app center.
but when i try to open it. it does not open. I have tried restarting and updating. what could be the reason

Run the command touchtyper in a terminal. What message does it show?

You can contact the developer here https://snapcraft.io/touch-typer
